# DNS works but SSH connection still fails with 'could not resolve hostname' on first attempt then starts to work after a few seconds

Tags: networking, ssh, git-bash

I have a Windows VM on Hyper-V for development. I push my commits to Github over SSH from Git Bash from it.

Every time I try to push or connect over SSH the connection attempt immediately fails with "could not resolve hostname". Repeated attempts fail again immediately. If I wait 5-10 seconds after the first connection attempt, then it starts to work for a while.

ssh-copy-id on the other hand is never able resolve DNS, even if ssh can.

DNS otherwise works, I can browse the web, use programs, nslookup resolves the domain etc... So this problem has something to do with Git-bash and the minimal Linux like system it comes with, not a generic DNS issue. I have no DNS issues from the Linux VM where ssh is used natively.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

The VM has two network interfaces:

- One that's provided by Hyper-V so it can access the internet.
- Another one to give a static IP to the VM so I can access it from other VMs. This interface has no internet access or DNS servers configured.

There is only one DNS server. The one that's provided by Hyper-V. So far I couldn't reproduce the problem with nslookup so I assume the problem is not there.

Comment: What DNS servers do you have configured? Can nslookup resolve the domain using _every_ server listed, individually?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes it can as I write in the question that DNS works. I only have issues when trying to ssh from Git Bash.

Comment: You only said nslookup in general resolves the domain, I'm asking about whether it can resolve the domain when told to use each of the configured servers individually. (The point is that nslookup doesn't use the Windows-provided DNS query calls, it does its own.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity There is only one DNS server and I couldn't reproduce the problem with nslookup with it. But ssh-copy-id always fails to resolve any domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution which is adding the offending server(s) into the hosts file. Since I don't SSH/Git to many servers, this works for me so far.

I'll leave this question open maybe later I can find the right answer.